# (Variable divided by Number) printed in float - Bash [wrong number]

Tags: bash, variables, numbers, integer

Here's my piece of code

```
if [ $totalavg -gt 1000000 ]; then
    printf "%0.1f MB/s (average)\n" $(echo "scale=1; $totalavg/100000" | bc)
elif [ $totalavg -gt 1000 ]; then
    printf "%0.1f KB/s (average)\n" $(echo "scale=1; $totalavg/1000" | bc)
else
    printf "%i B/s (average)\n" "$totalavg"
fi
```

totalavg variable is an integer grabbed from /proc/ files. It's all fine until the integer is greater than 1000 to reach one of the if statements and it turns out that

```
./script.sh: row (with second if above 1000): printf: 1.7: wrong number
```

I've lost 2 hours of time with probably this super basic laughable-at problem. But I just can't fix it and I don't know what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I literally copied your script, and tried all the following, everything works exactly as expected.

```
/tmp> totalavg=500 ./script.sh
500 B/s (average)
/tmp> totalavg=5000 ./script.sh
5.0 KB/s (average)
/tmp> totalavg=50000 ./script.sh
50.0 KB/s (average)
/tmp> totalavg=5000000 ./script.sh
50.0 MB/s (average)
/tmp> totalavg=50000000 ./script.sh
500.0 MB/s (average)
/tmp> totalavg=1000 ./script.sh
1000 B/s (average)
/tmp> totalavg=1001 ./script.sh
1.0 KB/s (average)
/tmp> totalavg=999 ./script.sh
999 B/s (average)
/tmp> totalavg=999999 ./script.sh
999.9 KB/s (average)
/tmp> totalavg=1000000 ./script.sh
1000.0 KB/s (average)
/tmp> totalavg=1000001 ./script.sh
10.0 MB/s (average)

/tmp> cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $totalavg -gt 1000000 ]; then
    printf "%0.1f MB/s (average)\n" $(echo "scale=1; $totalavg/100000" | bc)
elif [ $totalavg -gt 1000 ]; then
    printf "%0.1f KB/s (average)\n" $(echo "scale=1; $totalavg/1000" | bc)
else
    printf "%i B/s (average)\n" "$totalavg"
fi
```

Can you try maybe copying your script somewhere else, and running it there?  Or maybe your `$totalavg` environment variable isn't being set correctly.

Comment: It need not be an *environment* variable.

Comment: Ough...

Well my totalavg is calculated this way:


received1=$(awk 'FNR == 4 {print $2}' /proc/net/dev)

sleep 1s

received2=$(awk 'FNR == 4 {print $2}' /proc/net/dev)

let "totalavg=((received2+received1))"


Still don't know how to fix it on my side :(